# How can I change label number and text?

Tags: jquery, html

How can I make the label text change when suma=1?
And how can I make label3 and label4 disappear?

Thanks for the help!

```js
$('.radio').on('change', function(e) {


      if (suma == 1) {
        // schimbare intrebare
        $('h1').text('#2.Ce faci in timpul liber?');
        var label1 = $("label[for=radio1]");
        var label2 = $("label[for=radio2]");
        var label3 = $("label[for=radio3]");
        var label4 = $("label[for=radio4]");

        var apasat = $(this).attr('id');
        document.getElementById(apasat).checked = false;
        total += parseInt(document.getElementById(apasat).value);
        // label text

        suma++;

      }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="radio1" class="radio" / value="1" />
  <label for="radio1" style="color:black;font-family:impact;text-align:center;" id='r1'>Mate & Fizica</label>
</div>


<div>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="radio2" class="radio" / value="2" />
  <label for="radio2" style="color:black;font-family:impact;text-align:center;" id='r2'>Biologie & Chimie</label>
</div>

<div>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="radio3" class="radio" / value="2" />
  <label for="radio3" style="color:black;font-family:impact;text-align:center;" id='r3'>Informatica</label>
</div>

<div>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="radio4" class="radio" / value="2" />
  <label for="radio4" style="color:black;font-family:impact;text-align:center;" id='r4'>Limba romana</label>
</div>
```

How can I make the label text change when suma=1? And how can I make label3 and label4 disappear? 
My code is mostly code again :(

Comment: Please format your code so it's more readable

Comment: What do I have to do so when I press a checkbox the answer changes? I managed to change the question but the answer won't change? Also, how can I hide a label?

Comment: Are you asking how to set the text of an element?  `$('#yourLabel').text('some text')`  Or how to hide an element?  `$('#yourLabel').hide()`  Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: @David I tried changing the text of my label and it doesn't work :( I am stuck at changing the label text.

Comment: @VladJ: Maybe you could show that attempt in the question and indicate specifically how it fails from your debugging?  "I tried" doesn't describe an attempt, and "it didn't work" doesn't describe a problem.

Comment: @David $('label1').text('Mount Everest');

Comment: @VladJ: There is no HTML element called `<label1>`.  Are you looking for your label with an ID of `r1`?  That would be `$('#r1')`

Comment: btw, who's `suma` I can't see any initialization kind of thing for it. Is it some global variable?

Comment: suma=sum I forgot to edit.

Comment: @David Thank you! I solved it using your tips. But do I have to always use # when using JQuery?

Comment: @VladJ: You should definitely take a look at some jQuery samples and tutorials.  The syntax for the selector is very important, and is pretty much the core of what jQuery does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on comments to the question...

> $('label1').text('Mount Everest');

The jQuery selector is incorrect.  `'label1'` would be looking for an HTML element like this:

```
<label1 />
```

Naturally, such an element doesn't exist.  So the selector doesn't find anything.  (In jQuery, when that happens it just sort of silently continues.  This is why debugging is critical, so you can test your selectors and see if they find anything.)

Are you trying to find *this* element?:

```
<label for="radio1" style="color:black;font-family:impact;text-align:center;" id='r1'>Mate & Fizica</label>
```

Since it has an `id`, you can just reference that:

```
$('#r1').text('Mount Everest');
```

There are many ways to identify an element with selectors.  If an element has an `id` though, that generally simplifies it.